# Installing Bootstrap in Symfony 4 with encore

Tags: symfony, bootstrap-4, webpack-encore

I tried to follow instructions from documentation but it doesn't work.
Documentation:  https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html

The code I have:

assets/js/app.js

```
require('./assets/css/app.scss');
const $ = require('jquery');
```

in webpackconfig

```
.setOutputPath('public/build/')
.setPublicPath('/build')
.addEntry('js', './assets/js/app.js')
.enableSassLoader()
.autoProvidejQuery()
const $ = require('jquery');
```

base.html.twig

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('build/app.scss') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('~/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css') }}">
{% endblock %}
```

And the error message in my console

```
127.0.0.1/:7 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/~/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css 
net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
127.0.0.1/:6 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/build/app.scss net::ERR_ABORTED 404 
(Not Found)
app.js:11 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module ".assetscssapp.scss"
at webpackMissingModule (app.js:11)
at Object../assets/js/app.js (app.js:11)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 63d062e87dc6edab6451:19)
at bootstrap 63d062e87dc6edab6451:62
at bootstrap 63d062e87dc6edab6451:62
```

Thank you !

Comment: Why are you using backward slashes in your first require statement ?

Comment: that was the path I copy pasted from phpstorm, it's corrected now, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: The error message in question refers to the backslash issue. What error do you get after fixing it?

Comment: @JakubMatczak It's exactly the same errors in the console

Comment: I don't think you would get `Cannot find module ".assetscssapp.scss"` again after changing backslashes to slashes. How the 11th line of `app.js` looks now?

Comment: It's : require('./assets/css/app.scss');

Comment: In your webpack config you might have to enable jquery support by adding `.autoProvidejQuery()`. See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/legacy-apps.html

Comment: Its was already done @dbrumann     
    .enableSassLoader()
    .autoProvidejQuery()

Answer (score 0):

The files are only created if you have run encore:

[Yarn](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/webpack-encore-legacy/production-build):

```
yarn run encore production
yarn run encore dev
yarn run encore dev --watch
```

Then the files can be found unter "/public/build" and asset can find them.
If you make changes to the source files, you'll have to rerun encore. On dev you can use the "-- watch" command